# Change button title with css

Tags: css, wordpress

Good morning, Im sure im missing something obvious but I am struggling finding the correct CSS to change the button text on this page
http://www.inksharks.com/store/cart/
I want to change the text from "continue shopping" to Add to Order.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This isn´t css, is basic HTML

Answer (score 1):

It isn't in the CSS, rather it's in the HTML.

Here is the markup - it is in an `a` tag. Inside of `<div id="content" class="content clearfix">`

```
<a href="http://www.inksharks.com" class="Cart66ButtonSecondary" title="Continue Shopping">Continue Shopping</a>
```

Here is a modified version to include "Add to order":

```
<a href="http://www.inksharks.com" class="Cart66ButtonSecondary" title="Add to order">Add to order</a>
```

Note, the `title` attribute should be changed to match it - as @Andrew pointed out in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This is an HTML issue. The line of code you need to modify is:

```
<a class="Cart66ButtonSecondary" title="Continue Shopping" href="http://www.inksharks.com">Continue Shopping</a>
```